# Updating store url

Tags: url, ce-1.9.0.1

i have just setup a magento platform with two websites for two online stores.  I changed the base url of one website to www.mydomain.com/abc at the backend admin panel,  and removed files in var/cache.  But it shows 404 not found after refreshing the browser,  now i cannot go to the admin panel which is oricginvally www.mydomain.com/admin

Please help

Community edition 1.9.0.1

Answer (score 1):

If you changed the Base URL to "www.mydomain.com/abc", the Admin panel should now be located in "www.mydomain.com/abc/admin".

Do make sure that you have the proper files under the "abc" directory as otherwise it will definitely throw a 404 error as no Magento files exist.

If you need to change the Base URL back but cannot access the Admin panel, you can do so through the database: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/recover/restore_base_url_settings